# Simple method call in Xcode 5 and passed value won't change

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I'm a noob to Xcode and am reading the Big Nerd Ranch book and its asking me to do example programs in simple C to get me familiar with the language, however its asked me to create a program that calls a method from main and passes an int and does a square calculation and the printf to defog screen.  Here is the program:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doTheMath(int numberToSquare)
{
    int numberSquared = numberToSquare * numberToSquare;
    printf("%d squared is %d\n",numberToSquare,numberSquared);

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    doTheMath(5);
    return 0;

}
```

As you can see I am passing the value 5 to the method and it prints 25 on screen when i run the code.  IF I then change 5 to 15 to get it to write out a different value, it doesn't.  It still writes out 5 squared, not 25 squared.

In debug and step through the value is wrong and isn't changed.

I've closed the project and Xcode and still it doesn't work all of the time and then sometimes it does reflect the changed value.

The project Type is an OSX application / command-line tool. The project is stored on my NAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and when I test it in Xcode and change the 5 to 15 and run it, I get the correct answer returned.  Make sure you save your file after you make the change, and you could also try to clean your project (Product > Clean).

Sometimes Xcode just does strange things . . .

Comment: Thanks.  Saving the project doesn't fix it but doing the Product > Clean fixes this every time.  I can't surely be expected to do this each time I run the app?  Can you set a clean to run automatically on each run?  I can reproduce this each time.

Comment: I've just moved my project from a NAS/Shared drive locally and it works every time without fail or having to run Project > Clean. Thanks for your help.